# django model objects to a python list

Tags: django, django-models

I want to generate a list using my django model

say I have these model:

```
class AlarmServer(models.Model):
    ip = models.IPAddressField()
```

and such a list

```
server_ips = [i.ipfor i in AlarmServer.objects.all()]
```

Doesn't seem to work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work"? What does that mean? What happens when you try? What output do you get? What errors does it give?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
server_ips = [i.ip for i in AlarmServer.objects.all()]
```

Should work (I just added a space). I've tried this as below

```
mez@stupor % ./manage.py shell
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Oct  5 2008, 19:24:49) 
[GCC 4.3.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from mysite_org.videos.models import Video
>>> url_list = [v.url for v in Video.objects.all()]
>>> url_list
[u'http://media.mysite.org/videos/sblug_jan2009.flv', u'http://media.mysite.org/videos/sblug_feb2009.flv', u'http://media.mysite.org/videos/phpwm_mar2009.flv', u'http://media.mysite.org/videos/sblug_may2009.flv', u'http://media.mysite.org/videos/sblug_june2009.flv', u'http://media.mysite.org/videos/sblug_sep2009.flv', u'http://media.mysite.org/videos/bugjam-oct-2009.flv']
```

Comment: I think you can tag `.iterator()` to the end of this queryset for memory savings.  `AlarmServer.objects.all().iterator()`.  Check out: http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/lookup/

Answer (score 5):

[values_list](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list-fields)

```
server_ips = [i[0] for i in AlarmServer.objects.values_list('ip')]
```

Comment: No idea if this is what the OP wants, but you can avoid the list comprehension in your example by simply doing `AlarmServer.objects.values_list('ip', flat=True)`